# Modeling Antennas

Tags: packages, simulation

Radio amateurs often use [EZNEC](https://www.eznec.com/) to model antennas. I was wondering if anyone knows of a Mathematica code to model and simulate an antenna. I have not found anything with a google search.

Answer (score 8):

> I was wondering if anyone knows of a Mathematica code to model and
>   simulate an antenna. I have not found anything with a google search.

Actually Google returns multiple relevant results, here are some from the top 10:

- [Dipole Antenna Radiation Pattern](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DipoleAntennaRadiationPattern/)

  See the demonstrations related to that demonstration.
- [Open Antennas Mathematica Projects](http://www.antennas.gr/mathematica/)
- ["Modeling of antenna on package for the 60 GHz frequency band applications"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5650742/?reload=true)

Also, [SystemModeler](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/industry/electrical-engineering/) seems to have functions for antenna simulations.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the program linked by the OP can model much more complex geometries. Of course that software also is commercial, so unfortunately I don't have a better answer regarding *Mathematica*...(+1)